# printing skb data crashes computer when using netfilter hook

Tags: c, kernel, hook, netfilter

I'm trying to print data out of skbuffs using the netfilter hook functionality. The only problem is when i run this code, my OS freezes and a have to do a forced shutdown. Im new to kernel coding so i was hoping someone could take a look at this and explain how to fix.

One thing i have noticed is if i add a line at the very beginning of my hook_func "if (!sb) return NF_ACCEPT;" then the program runs fine. EDIT: accept no skb data is printed as the if statement is always initiated.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

/* This is the structure we shall use to register our function */ 
static struct nf_hook_ops nfho; 

/* This is the hook function itself */ 
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, 
struct sk_buff **skb, 
const struct net_device *in, 
const struct net_device *out, 
int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) 
{ 
    struct sk_buff *sb = *skb; 

    int kk=0; 
    for (kk=0; (kk<sb->len) && (kk < 300); kk++) 
            printk("%c", &sb->data+kk ); 
    printk("\n----------------\n"); 

    return NF_ACCEPT;
} 

/* Initialisation routine */ 
int init_module() 
{  
    /* Fill in our hook structure */ 
    nfho.hook = hook_func; 
    /* Handler function */ 
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; /* First for IPv4 */ 
    nfho.pf = PF_INET; 
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST; /* Make our func first */ 

    nf_register_hook(&nfho); 

    return 0; 
} 

/*Cleanup routine */ 
void cleanup_module() 
{ 
nf_unregister_hook(&nfho); 
}
```

I really need some help on this!
Cheers 
Ben

Comment: Sorry to ask you mate, what is skb?

Answer (score 0):

So answering my own question now. After some searching and further debugging i managed to find someone with a similar problem:

http://forum.kernelnewbies.org/read.php?15,1100,1100

It turns out that since "linux versions >= 2,6,20" the hook function does define skb in the same way. Now it is just a single pointer, so the hook function should look like this:

```
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, 
struct sk_buff *skb, 
const struct net_device *in, 
const struct net_device *out, 
int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) 
{ 
    struct sk_buff *sb = skb; 

    int kk=0; 
    for (kk=0; (kk<sb->len) && (kk < 300); kk++) 
            printk("%c", &sb->data+kk ); 
    printk("\n----------------\n"); 

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Notice the hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff **skb...) has now changed to hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb...)

and

struct sk_buff *sb = *skb; has now changed to struct sk_buff *sb = skb;

Hope this helps people who have had the same issue as me.

Comment: This no longer works with the latest changes in 3.13+ version of the kernel.